# coldfusion exchange connection to Office 365

Tags: coldfusion, exchange-server, coldfusion-9, office365

I'm trying to set up a cfexchangeconnection to our office365 server to retrieve calendar settings but can't get the connection settings right.

If i do:

```
<cfexchangeconnection
    action = "open"
    connection = "exCon"
    server = "outlook.office365.com"
    username = "email@address"
    password = "**********"
    port="995">
```

I get 500: Could not log in to the Exchange server. Verify server name, username, and password.

I don't know if this means its an auth issue or whether I just got the server name wrong

If I take the port setting off I get the same error.

The server name is the one provided for setting up mail using imap or pop. The username is just the email and the password is obvious....

Switching the protocol to https I get the following error:

```
Cannot access Exchange server as a web application at outlook.office365.com.
Ensure that the Exchange web application is configured in IIS and Web Service Extension for the Exchange server is allowed. HTTP response code : 404
```

Comment: Can you log into the site directly with the username and password?

Comment: Yes. The username and password do work. I have checked that.

Comment: I assume there is a certificate involved. When you log in directly is it secure?  ColdFusion might need that certificate.

Comment: it is https when i log in. When i switch the protocol to https I get this error: "Cannot access Exchange server as a web application at outlook.office365.com.
Ensure that the Exchange web application is configured in IIS and Web Service Extension for the Exchange server is allowed. HTTP response code : 404"

Comment: I downloaded the certificate through Outlook web access and installed it locally. Still getting this error: 
Cannot access Exchange server as a web application at outlook.office365.com.
Ensure that the Exchange web application is configured in IIS and Web Service Extension for the Exchange server is allowed. HTTP response code : 404

Comment: Did you restart ColdFusion after you imported the certificate?

Comment: Yes I did restart the ColdFusion Application Service.

Comment: Do you know if the _Web Service Extension for the Exchange server_ is enabled/allowed?

Comment: No i don't know, its all hosted at microsoft and its a little difficult to find this information out. I have posted a question in a forum to find out.

Comment: Did you get any more information about this or get it working?

Comment: not yet. Still passing the issue around

Comment: Microsoft have been no help whatsoever. Their tech support guys refused to answer basic questions about whether web services were even enabled on the system.  Is there a way i can check if the web service extension is enabled?

Comment: I have found https://outlook.office365.com/ews/Exchange.asmx I can connect to it in my browser and log in using my credentials if that helps

Answer (score 0):

The below configuration worked for me.  You have to install the certificate using keytool.exe.  Make sure to add the serverversion, and select 2010.  Also, make sure to specify https protocol.  The default is 2007.

```
<cfexchangeconnection action="open"
     username="#username#"
     password="#password#"
     mailboxname="#mailboxname#"
     server="outlook.office365.com"
     protocol="https"
     serverversion="2010"
     connection="testconn1"
     formBasedAuthentication="true"
     formBasedAuthenticationURL="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/auth/owaauth.dll">
```